# ArcGIS Online User object 'report' method/function errors

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, reports

According to the API docs for User object there is a 'report' function.
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.User

I have an Administrator user role.

When I attempt to get a report for a user as shown below...

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import datetime as _dt

## connect to portal
agol = GIS("home")

## logged in user - returns a User object
user = agol.users.me

## https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.User
seven_days_ago = _dt.datetime.now(_dt.timezone.utc) - _dt.timedelta(days=7)
item = user.report("content", seven_days_ago, duration="weekly")

print(item)
```

I get the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ArcGISPro\envs\arcgispro-py3-nbi\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py", line 7272, in __getattr__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, name)
KeyError: 'report'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\ArcGISPro\envs\arcgispro-py3-nbi\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py", line 7274, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'report'
```

Has anyone successfully ran a user report using this method?

Comment: What sort of AGOL account do you have? Creating a report is generally an administrative function. You may not have the required access for `report`

Comment: Hi @KHibma I am an Administrator, ill edit the question to include that detail. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the report function was added at 2.0.1. My arcgis package version was 1.9.1. Upgrading the version enabled the report function for a User object.

For added context, my ArcGIS Pro is version 2.8. I have a cloned python environment that I can update using the Python Package Manager, but there was no arcgis package update available here. I used the command prompt with...

```
pip install arcgis --upgrade
```

... this upgraded the arcgis package to 2.0.1.